# Can we change physics body properties in runtime - corona sdk

Tags: coronasdk

Can we change physics body properties in runtime. My code is

```
local ground = display.newImage( "ground.png" )
ground.x = 160; ground.y = 445
physics.addBody( ground, "static", { friction=0.5, bounce=0.3 } )
```

I want to change the bounce value need to 1.0 in run time, is it possible...

Can any one help me

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly change the body properties after creation, but you can change the properties of an individual collision using a pre-collision PhysicsContact handler. This tells the system that when the collision occurs, you wish to change the "bounce" value to something else, for that collision only.

This tutorial and the API documents should explain it better:

1. [Introducing Physics “event.contact”](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/11/27/introducing-physics-event-contact/)
2. [PreCollision (Corona API)](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/preCollision/index.html)
3. [object.bounce (Corona API)](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/PhysicsContact/bounce.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do physics:removebody (ground)
     physics:addbody(ground, new_properties)